# Page not displaying view as horizontal

Tags: theming

Cannot work out why in my view it is correctly displaying rows horizontally but not in page display where it is displaying vertical.

I've tried clearing all caches and have checked css for appearance which has float left and clear all so cannot understand it.

Using corporate clean layout. PER PAGE GALLERY for content type as well as display settings in view

Now i've added to css in theme where the class is "field-items"

.field-items {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0.5em 1em 0;
}

[image: gallerypageview]

[image: content]

[image: settings]

[image: viewgrab]

Comment: Please include a screenshot of what you're referring to, as well as details of the settings you are using

Comment: images in colorbox all set to page per gallery

Comment: "... have checked css for appearance which has float left and clear all ... " - You mean "clear: both"? That's what would make every item drop to a new line and make it vertical.

Comment: sorry i do mean clear:both

Comment: site is here http://stall4.notabadartist.com

Comment: am i not using correct class name - i don't know. the theme has basic-layout.css and out of css folder it has style.css

Comment: i want to ditch the views because i prefer theme layout on "YES" and just make horizontal

Comment: It looks like all the images are coming from a single node's field? So you need to look at the multi-value display settings of your image field in the view. It's showing each item separated with a comma at the moment. You might want to remove the commas from that settings. Then from CSS you just need to apply your styles to `a.colorbox { float: left; margin: 0 0.5em 1em 0; display: block; }`

Comment: put that in style.css?

Comment: @Beebee YAY YOU FIXED IT FOR ME! thank YOU! you should answer it now

Comment: @Beebee can you tell me why the style uploading directly to a page as oppsed to a view but still in colorbox is not the same? how can you transfer the style in theme to work also in view??

Comment: Not a very clear question. I suppose you're asking why the admin preview is different than the frontend display? It's because they're two different themes, admin preview is probably using the "Seven" admin theme, whereas your frontend display is using whatever theme that you've chosen. The frontend and the admin preview should be using the exactly the same template files (.tpl.php) but the loaded theme CSS can differ and hence show/render things differently.

Comment: actually no - images loaded in basic page content have style diff to images loaded in view..